# Can I send files one by one to the client with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Let's say I have a lot of images and it takes 1 hour to loop through them. I want to send to the client the images that suit a condition. I don't want to send all of them at the same time because the client will have to wait 1 hour to get the images. I want to send the images one at a time, as soon as each image passed the condition.

The code below won't send any file to the client because the object created by [`send_file`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/?highlight=send_file#flask.send_file) needs to be returned. Of course, if I return the object, only the first file will be sent.

```py
@app.route('/img_process', methods=['POST'])
def img_process():
    for file in files:
        if condition:
            send_file(photo_path, mimetype='image/jpg')
```

Comment: you can't  send one-by-one. But many pages uses lazy-loading - it means JavaScript code which loads image when you scroll page. Eventually you could use some pagination. Send few images and user has to click button to load more - and this also need JavaScript to add new images to current page. Or JavaScript can periodically asks server if there are new images to display. It may need to generate images to files in folder `/static` and send only url for this image (when it is ready) - and when JavaScript add `<img src=...` to HTML then browser will load it.

Comment: if it needs 1 hour to generate all images then you may need to start it as separated process and send only unique number to browser - and JavaScript should periodically send this unique number to other function which would send back links to all images already generated, and later JavaScript would add new links to page to display it. And JavaScript could also display some progressbar (if you know how many results it will get).

Comment: @furas Thanks for the tips! The first option would not be feasible for my application. The second one might work, but it seems to be a cumbersome solution. I was thinking of using Socket IO. This way I will set up a listener on the client-side and then emit each image one by one. I used Sockets IO a long time ago, so I'm not sure if it's possible. If it's not, I'll try your second method. I will try to keep this thread updated.

Comment: @furas I've handled it with Socket.IO after all. It was exactly what I wanted and it's easy to implement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I could find is by using web sockets, for example with [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/).

Here is how to do it:

1. Set up a listener on the front end:

```
// Socket listener for the "receive_image" event
socket.on('receive_image', (image) => {
  // Here you set the "src" of an image tag to be `image` (which is a string)
});
// Make a request to "img_process"
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/img_process');
```

2. Set up an emitter on the back end:

```
@app.route('/img_process', methods=['POST'])
def img_process():
    for file in files:
        if condition:
            # Load the image with OpenCV and convert it into text
            photo = cv2.imread('path/to/image')
            _, photo = cv2.imencode('.jpg', photo) # Change "jpg" to your file format of choice
            text_photo = base64.b64encode(photo).decode('utf-8')
            # Emit the image to the "receive_image" event which was set up in the front end.
            # Change "jpg" to the file format you chose.
            socketio.emit('receive_image', 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + text_photo)
```

Inspiration from https://gist.github.com/companje/b95e735650f1cd2e2a41 :)